Using printf from c in Nasm causes the string to add random end line statment
this morning i tried to make a simple output library for my asm projects, i realized using the sys call each time is a waste of time and so i decided to automatize the program using printf function from c, so i tried to make a function with a little help from git hub forums and a bit of ai explaining me how asm works and i came up with this code.
SECTION .data
    endLine db 0Ah, 0
    integer_printf:     db  '%d',   10,0
    float_printf        db  '%f',   10,0
    string_format       db  '%s',   10,0

SECTION .text
    extern printf

printStr:
    ; mov rsi, string please put rsi to have the same value as your string variable (pointer)
    mov rdi,string_format ; mov rdi,printf_format
    call printf
    ret


%include '../script.asm'
%include '../funcio.asm'

extern printf

global main

section .data
    float_point     dq     70.232
    integer_value   dq     33      
    string_value    db     "Hello world!", 0

section .text

main:
    movsd xmm0, [float_point]
    call printFloat
    mov rsi, [integer_value]
    call printInt

    mov rsi, string_value
    call printStr
    call printStr
    call printStr
    call printStr
    call printStr

    mov rdi, 0
    call exit_program

This code is subdivided in two files and for some reason when i print the string hello world it will increase the number of new lines each time a new print function is called.
those are the infos:
expected output:
33
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!

obtained output:
70.232000
33
Hello world!
Hello world!

Hello world!


Hello world!



Hello world!

thanks for any help in advice!

Are you sure the rsi register is preserved during calls to printf?

RSI and RDI are caller-saved in most calling conventions -- which means a function can use them at will without saving them (because the caller already did, if it cared about them).  For the same reason you don't have to push them before using them and pop them after, other functions don't either, so you can't rely on those registers to retain their values.
You'll need to reload them each time.
    ...
    mov rsi, string_value
    call printStr
    mov rsi, string_value
    call printStr
    mov rsi, string_value
    call printStr
    ...


Thanks man, now i gotta discover a way to stop ending the line each time i use that function.

@Hrodebert: You're the one including the newline in your format string.  :)  See the db '%s', 10, 0?  That 10 is a newline character.  If you get rid of it, the newlines go away.

Thanks man, this was really helpful, i wish i could up vote your question but i dont have enough karma so i will only set it to be the accepted answer, have a great day!

are you sure the 10 is the problem? if i remove it the printf statement wont work
i tried removing the 10 after the string but it wont work, if i set string_format       db  '%s'   ,0 like this the strings wont be printed

@Hrodebert: With stdio, you might not see results til you print a newline or flush to stdout.  You don't have to print one every time, but you should print one at the end.  Easy way: just have a newline string like db 10, 0 and print that after you've done all your hellos.

@cHaothanks, everything works now!

As long as your program exits via call exit or ret from main, not a raw _exit syscall, the stdout buffer will get flushed.  The normal convention is for program output to end with a newline, so that's a good idea, but not sufficient to guarantee your output actually outputs.  If redirected to a file, stdout will be full-buffered.  Using printf in assembly leads to empty output when piping, but works on the terminal  (@Hrodebert)

After some digging i discovered that the reason was that registers such as rsi are volatile and might lose the value over time thats why you have to re-set each register each call.
%include '../script.asm'
%include '../funcio.asm'

extern printf

global main

section .data
    float_point     dq     70.232
    integer_value   dq     33      
    string_value    db     "Hello world!", 0

section .text

main:
    movsd xmm0, [float_point]
    call printFloat
    mov rsi, [integer_value]
    call printInt

    mov rsi, string_value
    call printStr
    mov rsi, string_value
    call printStr
    mov rsi, string_value
    call printStr
    mov rsi, string_value
    call printStr
    mov rsi, string_value
    call printStr
    mov rsi, string_value

    mov rdi, 0
    call exit_program




It's not that they lose their values "over time" as if by radioactive decay or something (the word "volatile" is perhaps misleading in this way) but simply that the code inside printf is allowed to overwrite them without restoring the original value afterwards.

The rsi and rdi registers are caller saved -- YOU calling printf being the caller at that point in your program. YOU must preserved rsi and rdi if you need the values that exist at the time of your call to printf, because printf is free to do whatever it wants with those registers. I guess the AI help must have been hallucinating when it forgot to mention that. (not a big fan of magic thinking that AI knows what it is doing -- it doesn't it simply regurgitates what it was trained on -- and not all asm sites are that good)

What are callee and caller saved registers? / What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call
